# Bind enabled of NSButton to selection in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, selection, nstextview

I have a button that does something to the selected text in NSTextView. If nothing is selected then nothing happens when the button is pressed... so can the enabled property of a button be bound to whether or not some text is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to bind a view to another view, anyway. The Right Way is to bind views to controllers, and Bindings gets cranky when you don't do things the Right Way.

Bind the button's `enabled` property to a property of the controller. Have the controller be the delegate of the text view, and when [the text view's selections change](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextViewDelegate/textView:willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:toCharacterRanges:), update the controller's property accordingly.

If no text (was|is) selected, then the (old|new) selection ranges array will contain exactly one NSValue object, whose `rangeValue` will be a zero-length range. This range is that of the insertion point; its length will be zero (nothing selected), but its location may not be (it will be wherever the insertion point is).

Comment: Good idea Peter. Works perfect. I just set a BOOL value in the text view's delegate in that method and then bind to that. Thanks for the idea!